# Random in .lua programming

Tags: random, lua

I have to make a random numer (1 and 2) in .lua, and change this value every 3 seconds.

I have a variable = `randomMode`, this `randomMode` have to change every 3 seconds (1 or 2)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/18.html)

Comment: local time1 = os.time()

mode = getmode

function GetMode()
    local time2 = os.time()
 while (time2 - time1 > 3)
        time2 = time1
        mode = math.random(1, 2)
    end
    return mode
end

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a kind of timer that changes the value. For example the main program loop could to change the variable every 3 seconds by using time stamps.

If you cant use a good way to implement a timer, maybe just checking time stamps since last call is good enough. For example this function randomizes the number on each call to `GetRandomMode` if more than 3 seconds has passed:

```
local lastChange = os.time()
local mode = math.random(1, 2)
function GetRandomMode()
    local now = os.time()
    if os.difftime(now, lastChange) > 3 then
        lastChange = now
        mode = math.random(1, 2)
    end
    return mode
end
```

Comment: I can not use the "if" because between "last change" and "now" will never have 3 seconds. The mode will always be on just one result.

Comment: @YuriGiles Not sure what you mean.
The function above changes the output every 3 seconds with this code: `while true do print(GetRandomMode()) end`. I edited the code a bit just now since difftime returned negative result.